# Why can a std::vector of uncopiable objects not be initialized with an initializer_list?

Tags: c++11, stdvector, initializer-list

Why does this not compile? (it needs a copy-constructor for std::unique_ptr<>)

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec{std:unique_ptr<int>(new int)};
```

The created pointer is an r-value so why can it not be moved into the vector?

Is there an equally short way of initializing the vector that works?

Comment: `std::initializer_list` is kind of broken for move-only types. There are a few proposals to fix this, such as [this one](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4166.pdf).

Comment: Really for 2011, not 2014? `std::make_unique` is available since c++14, not c++11; according to Herb Sutter, leaving that out was 'partly an oversight' in the 2011 standardization process; is it foreseeable that someone will look into the standard for this, and it should be the right standard then.

Comment: @decltype_auto: I removed the use of std::make_unique() instead of changing the tag, because the core problem of the question exists in c++11

Comment: Not about the initializer/unique_ptr standard conformance issue itself, but if you need that efficiency right now in a project -you can create an empty vector, and then emplace_back the unique_ptr.

Comment: A possible workaround is to create a raw array of unique_ptrs (`ptrs`), and then to call `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec(std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(ptrs)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(ptrs)));`

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki: This works, but it looks rather verbose, I would prefer the emplace_back() for vectors with view elements. It might be usefull for larger vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The simple problem is that `std::unique_ptr`'s copy-ctor is `deleted`, but the `construct` of `std::` that is found invokes `::new` which triggers a call to that deleted copy-ctor.

libc++/clang++-3.5

/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:1645:31: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr >'

```
template <class _Up, class... _Args>
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
void
construct(_Up* __p, _Args&&... __args)
{
    ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
}
```

libstdc++/g++-4.9

```
 /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function 
‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) 
[with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]’
         { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

It somewhat tempting to try and formulate a custom overload of [std::allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) as use it for the container's allocator type.

**For those who cannot resist that temptation** (like me)

To make a custom allocator at least *used* by the compiler it at least needs this minimum population.

```
template<typename T>
struct allocator : public std::allocator<T> {
    using Base = std::allocator<T>;
    using Base::Base;

    template<typename U>
    struct rebind {typedef allocator<U> other;};

    template<typename Up, typename... Args>
    void construct(Up* p, Args&&... args);
};
```

That is hardly complete yet (let alone would I have `construct` properly re-implemented yet), but at least it summons the error up from the abysses of the lib into the daylight a custom source file.

Comment: I do not really understand what you are getting at. Will using your allocater make the line of code work?

Comment: @Knitschi: at least that's what aim at, but that is an ansatz yet. Btw that `Args&&... args`in the bugged `construct`call evaluates to a const std::unique_ptr&.